# CSS: place three.js within circular div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to place multiple divs in a line horizontally across the screen with with three.js animations WITHIN them, as in the circular div is the parent to the div containing the three.js. Ultimately I want these circles to be able to scroll horizontally across my screen.

I have succeeded in creating a horizontal lineup of circular divs and partially placing my three.js div within them, however I am unable to center my animation within the parent circular div and am having issues achieving a perfect circle. I'm new to this and am having trouble finding the best way to achieve this. Here is what I have so far: 
CSS:

```
.circle {
    display: table;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
                margin: 50px auto;
                background-color: lightgray;
                height: 100px;
                width: 0;
}
#planet {


    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align:center;
    left:10%;
    position:relative; /*makes left effective*/
    display:table-cell;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper" style="background-color:lightgrey;">
<div class="container">
<h1 id="titleHead">Projects</h1>
    <a href="">
        <ul>
        <div class ="circle">
        <div id ="planet"></div>
        </div>
        </ul>
    </a>
</div>
</div>
<script src="js/lowpolyPlanets.js"></script>  
</body>
```

This is what this creates: 
[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have a perfect circle, you have to set the height and width the same value (as my example). For the other issue, setting the `left` property push it on right, but without the JS code of your "planet", it would be hard to solve.

```css
.circle {
    display: table;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
                margin: 50px auto;
                background-color: lightgray;
                height: 100px;
                width: 100px;
}
#planet {


    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align:center;
    left:10%;
    position:relative; /*makes left effective*/
    display:table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper" style="background-color:lightgrey;">
<div class="container">
<h1 id="titleHead">Projects</h1>
    <a href="">
        <ul>
        <div class ="circle">
        <div id ="planet"></div>
        </div>
        </ul>
    </a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Now having issues adding more divs, would you look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37223154/html-css-display-circular-divs-in-horizontal-scrolling-lineup-divs-appear-on-t