# HTML/CSS: display circular divs in horizontal scrolling lineup? Divs appear on top of each other?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have succeeded in centering a div containing a three.js animation within another circular div by setting the outer div to display of table and placing this all within a ul. I

I am having problems however creating a horizontal lineup of these circular divs (with another div within each) using li - no matter the padding I use, all the divs appear on top of each other. I ultimately want these divs to scroll horizontally but haven't begun to tackle that issue.
Here is a screenshot of my problem:[image]

CSS:

```
.circle1 {
    background: #50a3a2;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top left, #50a3a2 0%, #53e3a6 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #50a3a2 0%, #53e3a6 100%);
    display: table;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 50px auto;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
.circle2 {
    background: #000;
    display: table;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 50px auto;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
#btn1 {

    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align:center;
    left:0%;
    position:relative; /*makes left effective*/
    display:table-cell;
}
#btn2 {
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align:center;
    left:0%;
    position:relative; /*makes left effective*/
    display:table-cell;
}
ul {

}
li {
    display: table;
list-style-type: none;
padding: 20px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper" style="background-color:lightgrey;">
<div class="container">
<h1 id="titleHead">Projects</h1>
    <a href="">
        <ul>
        <li>
        <div class ="circle1">
        <div id ="btn1"></div>
        </div>
        </li>
        <li>
        <div class ="circle2">
        <div id ="btn2"></div>
        </div>
        </li>
        </ul>
    </a>
</div>
</div>
<script src="js/lowpolyPlanets.js"></script>  
<script src="js/test2.js"></script>
```

What's going wrong here?

EDIT - li elements are skewed to the left:

CSS-

```
.circle1 {
    background: #50a3a2;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top left, #50a3a2 0%, #53e3a6 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #50a3a2 0%, #53e3a6 100%);
    display: table;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
    margin: 50px auto;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
.circle2 {
    background: #000;
    display: table;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
    margin: 50px auto;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
#btn1 {

    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align:center;
    left:0%;
    position:relative; /*makes left effective*/
    display:table-cell;
}
#btn2 {
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align:center;
    left:0%;
    position:relative; /*makes left effective*/
    display:table-cell;
}
.ulContainer {
    text-align: center;
}
ul {
    margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    background-color: red;

}
li {

    float: left;
list-style-type: none;
padding: 20px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper" style="background-color:lightgrey;">
<div class="container">
<h1 id="titleHead">Projects</h1>
    <div class = "ulContainer">
        <ul>
        <li>
        <div class ="circle1">
        <div id ="btn1"></div>
        </div>
        </li>
        <li>
        <div class ="circle2">
        <div id ="btn2"></div>
        </div>
        </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to make it look like below?

[image]

If yes then, Give `float:left` to your `li` and try removing circle1's position or changing it to relative.

Comment: Thank you, although now having problem with centering - the circular divs are slightly to the left. I've updated my code and placed a wrapper div around the ul and tried to center that however the li elements remain to the left

Comment: Welcome, for making it center, you will have to make following changes
1) add `<div style="clear:both"></div>` after completion of your last `<li>`
2) give `<ul>' a style, ie. `display:inline-block`
3) give its parent's `<a>` tag a style like `display: block; text-align: center;`